# Is it possible to change Finish button text to Done in Wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have created a custom wizard with some pages in eclipse plugin. The pages are created by extending the WizardPage. The wizard has Next back Finish and cancel button, and everything works fine.
Now, I want to change the name/text of Finish button to Done. Is it possible to do this in eclipse? Or will I need to provide all the buttons by myself, even this would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);

    Button finish = getButton(IDialogConstants.FINISH_ID)
    finish.setText("Done");
    setButtonLayoutData(finish);
}
```

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459946/jface-swt-change-the-labels-for-buttons-in-inputdialog) is a related question.

Comment: Well in the org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard class I cannot override that method! This worked with dialog not with wizard!! Where exactly should I use this?

Comment: This is in `WizardDialog`. Depending on what sort of wizard you are using this may not be usable directly.

Comment: @Destructor Ah, my bad. Could you please post some code, so we can see what you're actually doing/using?

Comment: Got it by using the same approach! I will post the answer below.
@greg-449: Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 2):

So this is how I was using the wizard:

```
MyCustomWizard wizard = new MyCustomWizard ("title");
WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), wizard);
wizardDialog.open();
```

Now I created a new class, MyCustomDialog extending the WizardDialog:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends WizardDialog {

public MyCustomDialog(Shell parentShell, IWizard newWizard) {
    super(parentShell, newWizard);
}

@Override
public void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent){
    super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);
    Button finishButton = getButton(IDialogConstants.FINISH_ID);
    finishButton.setText(windowTitle);
}
}
```

And now I changed the code where I create wizard and wizard dialog as:

```
MyCustomWizard wizard = new MyCustomWizard ("title");
MyCustomDialog wizardDialog = new MyCustomDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), wizard);
wizardDialog.open();
```

Hope it is useful to someone! :)
Thanks for the help @greg-449 and @Baz

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to change the label of any button. You can override createButton of WizardDialog class as :

```
@Override
protected Button createButton(Composite parent, int id, String label,
            boolean defaultButton) {
        if (id == IDialogConstants.FINISH_ID) {
            return super.createButton(parent, id,
                    "Done", defaultButton);
        }
        return super.createButton(parent, id, label, defaultButton);
}
```